# Read an encrypted value across machines

Tags: c#, .net, encryption

I'm trying to write out encrypted data in such a way that the same user account (on a domain) can read the data from a different machine than the one that wrote it - *but only that user can*. It looks like the `System.Security.Cryptography.ProtectedData` class doesn't work that way. It's a command line tool.

```
var encryptedData = ProtectedData.Protect(data, null, DataProtectionScope.CurrentUser);
```

Is there another way to encrypt data with .Net that will allow such access?

Comment: @Igor The `DpapiDataProtector` does (which led me in that direction), and that's the behavior I observed. I wrote a file from my personal machine using my user account, and when I read it on a server logged in as myself over RDP, it got `System.Security.Cryptography.CryptographicException: Key not valid for use in specified state`

Comment: Sorry again. The type you are looking for is `System.Web.Security.MachineKey` but you must have identical `machineKey` section values in your `app.config`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [System.Web.Security.MachineKey](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.machinekey(v=vs.110).aspx) but you have to make sure that the applications have the same configuration in their respective `app.config`/`web.config` files for the [machineKey](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w8h3skw9(v=vs.85).aspx) section. It can be found here in the configuration:

```
<configuration>
  <system.web>
    <machineKey decryption="[type]" decryptionKey="[value]" validation="[value]" validationKey="value" />
```

There are plenty of tools you can use to generate the values including IIS if you have an asp.net site configured.

Example with an actual key I generated from IIS in section `ASP.NET` => `Machine Key`.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var encrypted = Encrypt("this will be encrypted");
    Console.WriteLine("Encrypted base64: " + encrypted);
    Console.WriteLine();


    var unencrypted = Unencrypt(encrypted);
    Console.WriteLine("Decrypted: " + unencrypted);

    Console.ReadLine();
}

static string Encrypt(string valueToEncrypt)
{
    var toEncrypt = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(valueToEncrypt);
    var encryptedData = System.Web.Security.MachineKey.Protect(toEncrypt, null);
    var result = Convert.ToBase64String(encryptedData);
    return result;
}

static string Unencrypt(string value)
{
    var toUnencrypt = Convert.FromBase64String(value);
    var deencryptedData = System.Web.Security.MachineKey.Unprotect(toUnencrypt, null);
    var originalValue = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(deencryptedData);
    return originalValue;
}
```

Comment: This is a desktop command line tool, so it has an app.config. Is the section still `system.web`?

Comment: @Dov - correct, the section location in the config file is the same regardless of the type of app.

Comment: I tried this now (took me a little bit to generate keys, since I'm not using ASP.Net - I used a tweaked version of the code in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30652599/105717), and I didn't see any difference. I added the `system.web` section alongside the `configSections` section, and also added a reference to `System.Web.dll`.

Comment: @Dov - I have no problems, I edited my answer with a full working sample.

Comment: @Dov - Sorry, I made a mistake. You can do this with `System.Web.Security.MachineKey`, I updated my answer and example code. This makes use of the section I had listed in the `app.config`

Comment: Is that still tied down to the user account? Or is it machine only? You can use `ProtectedData` with `LocalMachine` scope.

Comment: @Dov - The `protect`/`unprotect` takes the application's `app.config` (or `web.config`) file into consideration. If section `machineKey` is defined with values that is used, if the section is not present or missing values then the PC's `machine.config` file is used.

Comment: @Dov - There is no LocaliMachine / User scope option for [MachineKey](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.machinekey(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: Thanks for offering this approach anyway

Comment: @Dov - you can still use the entropy and vary that per user. That will still give you what you want, I just meant there is no enumeration like there was in the `ProtectedData.Protect` method you were using.

Comment: @Dov - see the second parameter in the method named `purpose`. You can use whatever you want here and trying to decrypt an encrypted string with 2 different purposes would fail.

Comment: Sure, but anyone could use the user name of someone else to get access to the encrypted data, right? It loses its security that way

Comment: @Dov - It does not really matter what you put in there. For example: `asp.net identity` uses a random `guid` stored in the user's profile. You could write some value to the user`s profile, to their `app.config` instance at deploy time, etc, and use that value as a purpose in the Protect/Unprotect calls.

Comment: @Dov - Any solution you choose that can encrypt and decrypt only for a specific user/account would need to associate some type of entropy or key value to the user's account/profile. That is just the nature of the beast.

Comment: @Dov - That comes back down to key management which is a whole different problem. The above solution with `MachineKey` is what you will want if this is what you want to do though.

Comment: @Dov - I'll leave you alone. If you feel the answer was helpful I am always appreciative of an upvote and if you feel like it answered your question consider marking it as the answer. Good luck with whatever direction you end up taking.